# How can I detect rotation of Windows Phone 8 without using page orientation?

Tags: windows-phone-8

When a Windows Phone device is rotated to landscape, the page orientation tells me using an event with an enumeration. However, I'm trying to detect the landscape orientation without actually allowing the page to change orientation.

So, with Portrait being the only supported orientation on a page, how can I detect this same movement using the sensors? What values should I be looking for?

Answer (score 2):

Calculate angle using accelerometer maybe, then you can decide whether phone is in Landscape or Potrait mode from angle value. Following snippet is not tested and I haven't played with accelerometer so far, just to give an idea to start :

```
private Accelerometer _accel = new Accelerometer();

public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _accel.ReadingChanged += (s, e) => Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                            {
                                var angle = Math.Atan2(-x,y) * 180.0 / Math.PI;
                                .....
                            });
    _accel.Start();
}
```

References :

- Angle calculation : [WP7 Detect the screen orientation change when
  SupportedOrientations=“Portrait”](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e55d8368-4555-4492-8305-7109a96e05c1/wp7-detect-the-screen-orientation-change-when-supportedorientationsportrait?forum=wpdevelop)
- Using accelerometer : [Using the Accelerometer in Silverlight for Windows Phone](http://www.wintellect.com/blogs/jprosise/using-the-accelerometer-in-silverlight-for-windows-phone)

Comment: I still don't understand what to do. We have the Motion API which gives us Acceleration, Attitude (Pitch, Roll, Yaw), etc. But I have no idea how to harness this information.

Comment: +1, @Laith - compare position of the phone relative to the gravity. Phone has three accelerometers, which you can use for that purpose.